# How to resolve disk space problem in Ubuntu while using apt-get -f install?

Tags: 12.04, apt

When I use the command `apt-get -f install`, I received the following error

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-65-generic-pae_3.2.0-65.99_i386.deb (--unpack):
failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during './boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-65-generic-pae': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-65-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-65-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-65-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-65-generic-pae
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-65-generic-pae_3.2.0-65.99_i386.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `df` command.

Answer (score 0):

Run second terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or go to the first console <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and in there type:

`du ~ -h|sort -r -n|less`

at the top of your screen you will see the biggest files first trough whole you `/home` folder and all subfolders. You can delete some files and free space. Then continue with installation with `apt-get install`:

- `-f` fix broken packages
- `-r` remove packages
- `--reinstall` says for itself

or with `apt-get purge` is identical to `remove` except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too).